# How to store user input in an array without a for loop in c

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop

I connected a display with a keyboard to a Raspberry Pi and when I press a key, it displays the key on the screen. I am using [this](https://github.com/4dsystems/ViSi-Genie-RaspPi-Library/blob/master/geniePi.c) library and parts of [this](https://github.com/4dsystems/ViSi-Genie-RaspPi-Demo-Calculator/blob/master/calculator.c) program.

So I understood that this code passes the key to my `keyboardKey` function.

```
 if (reply->object == GENIE_OBJ_KEYBOARD)
      {
        if (reply->index == 0)  // Only one keyboard
          keyboardKey (reply->data) ;
```

The `keyboardKey` function then displays the key on the screen and saves the value into the `buf` array.

```
void keyboardKey (int key)
{
   char buf[4] ;
   int i ;
   printf("you typed %c\n",key) ;   //shows the typed key in the terminal
   sprintf(buf, "%c",key);         //transforms the key into a string which is required for using genieWrite    
   genieWriteStr (1, buf) ;       //writes the string to the screen. 1 is the index of the text box
   buf[i] = key ;                //stores the key in the array
   printf("%c\n",buf[0]);        //prints the array [0] in the terminal
}
```

The problem is it only shows one input. Everytime when a key is pressed it gets overwritten and the textbox only shows the last input. But what I want is for example to display a name.

So therefore I have to store each key that is passed to the function into the array without overwriting any of the previous ones.

I know how to store and print user input from the terminal with `scanf` or `getchar` and the use `for loops` to store and print the output, however here I am stuck. I was thinking of using `i++` at the end but then what value should `i` get in the first place?

Anyone an idea or a term I could google for, I'm pretty sure this is a common problem?

Comment: Is the buf string used in keyboardKey() function or outside that function? If it is used inside, you can define a static string, and a static int index which initially set to 0. Each time you read a key, you copy that to ith place in the string and move i by 1. If you are useing buf outside the keyboardKey() function, you may need to define the string outside the function, and pass the string as a parament to the function.

Comment: You have `char buf[4];` and are using it as a string. (e.g. `printf("%c\n",buf[0]);`) that means you have at most `3` characters you can store in `buf` (reserving the last, `buf[3]` for the null-terminating character `0`). You can use `static int i;` causing `i` to retain it's last value on each function call, enabling you to use `buf ` as a ring-buffer to that extent (e.g. at the end, `i++; if (i == 3) i = 0;`). Or, you can change the return `char keyboardKey (int key)` and store each key as it is returned. There are many ways to approach this.

Comment: thanks ! that helped a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure what you're trying to accomplish. Anyway, if you want to store your buffer's state in each call of `keyboardKey`, you could declare it as static like below:

```
#define BUF_SIZE 4

void keyboardKey(int key) {
  static char buf[BUF_SIZE];
  static int  i = 0;

  if(i > ((int)sizeof(buf) - 2)) {
    i = 0;
    memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));
  }

  printf("you typed %c\n",key);
  buf[i] = key; 

  genieWriteStr (1, buf);

  buf[i++] = key;
  printf("%s\n",buf);
}
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/228a4ff3593cdec1)

Comment: That works, thank you so much! but can you explain or maybe post a website to a tutorial what does this line mean `(int)sizeof(buf) - 2)`? Why `-2`?

Comment: @PaulBernhardWagner You have a buffer of N elements (i.e., `N = sizeof(buf)`), -1 element for the `\0` terminating character in order for your buffer to be interpreted as a valid string, you have left with N - 1 usable elements. Now C counts from 0, thus the index `i` must take values from the sequence `{0, 1, 2, ..., N - 2}`.  Consequently, when the index reaches a value that is greater than `N - 2`, the buffer along with the associated index must be reset. That's why the -2. Hope that cleared things out for you.